# JAXB: XmlAdapter for List<Object> items

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

Does anybody know how to attach custom `XmlAdapter` to objects contained in heterogenous list (like List)?
For example - suppose we have a container class with a list of miscelaneous objects:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "container")
public class Container {
    private List<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    public List<Object> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<Object> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }   
}
```

If we put `String`-s, `Integer`-s and so on they will be mapped by default. Now suppose we want to put a custom object:

```
public class MyObject {
    //some properties go here   
}
```

The obvious solution is to write a custom adapter:

```
public class MyObjectAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, MyObject> {
    //marshalling/unmarshalling
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work with package-level `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` - adapter just never called so marhalling fails.
And I can't apply it to `getValues()` directly because there can be other types of objects.
`@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` only works if I have a field of MyObject type in Container (also with package-level annotaton):

```
public class Container {
    private MyObject myObject;
}
```

But this is not what I want - I want a list of arbitrary objects. I'm using standard Sun's JAXB implementation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3-1</version>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas how to do the mapping?

P.S.: One small clarification - I'd like to avoid annotating `MyObject` with JAXB annotations. It may be a class from third-party library which is not under my control. So any changes should be outside of `MyObject`.

Comment: A `ContextResolver` could be a good solution here...

Answer (score 1):

You could try to change your `MyObjectAdapter` so that extends `XmlAdapter<String, List<Object>>`. So it should look something like this:

```
public class MyObjectAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, List<Object>> {
    //marshalling/unmarshalling
}
```

When you also add a XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation to the getter in your `Container` class, it should work.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "container")
public class Container {
    private ArrayList<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyObjectAdapter.class)
    public ArrayList<Object> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(ArrayList<Object> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your marshalling code. As I have same scenario to implement and to create the XML structure containing list of object and I have already used XmlAdapter<String, List<Object>> but resulting XML is containing only 1 object instead list of objects. Here is my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589574/xmladapter-for-marshalling-unmarshalling-list-of-object-using-jaxb-api Thanks.!